# WEBRTC: Local streams are visible on OPENVIDU WEB(other Participant) end But Remote Streams are coming NIL on my end locally swift iOS

Tags: swift, websocket, video-streaming, webrtc-ios, openvidu

I am using OpenVidu for Video Chat, Using this Repo https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-ios-app I know this has bugs, but I have to use this as This is working fine at Android and WEB. I am able to make it working where my Local video can be seen on OpenVidu Web but Remote or other person who has joined session from Web whose video(Video Stream and Audio Stream) is not coming at my end. however I can see Remote Participant ID and Name at my end when a user joined the session.

Attached Image is the screen shot showing Remote streams are nil.

[image]

Below is the WebSocketListener Class I am using, I have updated pods so have to update delegates as well.

```
//
//  WebSocketListener.swift
//  WebRTCapp
//
//  Created by Sergio Paniego Blanco on 01/05/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Sergio Paniego Blanco. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import Starscream
import WebRTC

class WebSocketListener: WebSocketDelegate {


    let JSON_RPCVERSION = "2.0"
    let useSSL = true
    var socket: WebSocket
    var helloWorldTimer: Timer?
    var id = 0
    var url: String
    var sessionName: String
    var participantName: String
    var localOfferParams: [String: String]?
    var iceCandidatesParams: [[String:String]]?
    var userId: String?
    var remoteParticipantId: String?
    var participants: [String: RemoteParticipant]
    var localPeer: RTCPeerConnection?
    var peersManager: PeersManager
    var token: String
    var views: [UIView]!
    var names: [UILabel]!
    var key: String?

    init(url: String, sessionName: String, participantName: String, peersManager: PeersManager, token: String, views: [UIView], names: [UILabel]) {
        self.url = url
        self.sessionName = sessionName
        self.participantName = participantName
        self.participants = [String: RemoteParticipant]()
        self.peersManager = peersManager
        self.token = token

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.timeoutInterval = 20
        socket = WebSocket(request: request)
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
        self.localPeer = self.peersManager.localPeer
        self.iceCandidatesParams = []
        self.views = views
        self.names = names

    }

//    func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocketClient) {
//        print("Connected")
//        pingMessageHandler()
//        var joinRoomParams: [String: String] = [:]
//        joinRoomParams["recorder"] = "false"
//        joinRoomParams["platform"] = "iOS"
//        joinRoomParams[JSONConstants.Metadata] = "{\"clientData\": \"" + "iOSUser" + "\"}"
//        joinRoomParams["secret"] = "MY_SECRET"
//        joinRoomParams["session"] = sessionName
//        joinRoomParams["token"] = token
//        sendJson(method: "joinRoom", params: joinRoomParams)
//        if localOfferParams != nil {
//            sendJson(method: "publishVideo",params: localOfferParams!)
//        }
//    }

    func pingMessageHandler() {
        helloWorldTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(WebSocketListener.doPing), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        doPing()
    }

    @objc func doPing() {
        var pingParams: [String: String] = [:]
        pingParams["interval"] = "5000"
        sendJson(method: "ping", params: pingParams)
        socket.write(ping: Data())
    }
    var isConnected = false
    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocketClient, error: Error?) {
        print("Disconnect: " + error.debugDescription)
    }
    func didReceive(event: WebSocketEvent, client: WebSocket) {
       switch event {
       case .connected(let headers):
           isConnected = true
        print("websocket is connected: \(headers)")
        pingMessageHandler()
        var joinRoomParams: [String: String] = [:]
        joinRoomParams["recorder"] = "false"
        joinRoomParams["platform"] = "iOS"
        joinRoomParams[JSONConstants.Metadata] = "{\"clientData\": \"\(self.participantName)\"}"
        joinRoomParams["secret"] = ""
        joinRoomParams["session"] = sessionName
        joinRoomParams["token"] = token
        sendJson(method: "joinRoom", params: joinRoomParams)
        if localOfferParams != nil {
            sendJson(method: "publishVideo",params: localOfferParams!)
        }
       case .disconnected(let reason, let code):
           isConnected = false
           print("websocket is disconnected: \(reason) with code: \(code)")
       case .text(let string):
           print("Received text: \(string)")

        let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
        do {
            let json: [String: Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as! [String : Any]

            if json[JSONConstants.Result] != nil {
                handleResult(json: json)
            } else {
                handleMethod(json: json)
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("ERROR parsing JSON: ", error)
        }
       case .binary(let data):
           print("Received data: \(data.count)")
       case .ping(_):
           break
       case .pong(_):
           break
       case .viabilityChanged(_):
           break
       case .reconnectSuggested(_):
           break
       case .cancelled:
           isConnected = false
       case .error(let error):
           isConnected = false
           print(error.debugDescription)
       }
    }

//    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {
//        print("Recieved message: " + text)
//        let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
//        do {
//            let json: [String: Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as! [String : Any]
//
//            if json[JSONConstants.Result] != nil {
//                handleResult(json: json)
//            } else {
//                handleMethod(json: json)
//            }
//
//        } catch let error as NSError {
//            print("ERROR parsing JSON: ", error)
//        }
//    }

    func handleResult(json: [String: Any]) {
        let result: [String: Any] = json[JSONConstants.Result] as! [String: Any]
        if result[JSONConstants.SdpAnswer] != nil {
            saveAnswer(json: result)
        } else if result[JSONConstants.SessionId] != nil {
            if result[JSONConstants.Value] != nil {
                let value = result[JSONConstants.Value]  as! [[String:Any]]
                if !value.isEmpty {
                    addParticipantsAlreadyInRoom(result: result)
                }
                self.userId = result[JSONConstants.Id] as? String
                for var iceCandidate in iceCandidatesParams! {
                    iceCandidate["endpointName"] = self.userId
                    sendJson(method: "onIceCandidate", params:  iceCandidate)
                }
            }
        } else if result[JSONConstants.Value] != nil {
            print("pong")
        } else {
            print("Unrecognized")
        }
    }

    func addParticipantsAlreadyInRoom(result: [String: Any]) {
        let values = result[JSONConstants.Value] as! [[String: Any]]
        for participant in values {
            print(participant[JSONConstants.Id]!)
            self.remoteParticipantId = participant[JSONConstants.Id]! as? String
            let remoteParticipant = RemoteParticipant()
            remoteParticipant.id = participant[JSONConstants.Id] as? String
            let metadataString = participant[JSONConstants.Metadata] as! String
            let data = metadataString.data(using: .utf8)!
            do {
                if let metadata = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String,Any>
                {
                    remoteParticipant.participantName = metadata["clientData"] as? String
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
            self.participants[remoteParticipant.id!] = remoteParticipant
            self.peersManager.createRemotePeerConnection(remoteParticipant: remoteParticipant)
            let mandatoryConstraints = ["OfferToReceiveAudio": "true", "OfferToReceiveVideo": "true"]
            let sdpConstraints = RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: mandatoryConstraints, optionalConstraints: nil)
            remoteParticipant.peerConnection!.offer(for: sdpConstraints, completionHandler: {(sessionDescription, error) in
                print("Remote Offer: " + error.debugDescription)
                self.participants[remoteParticipant.id!]!.peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription!, completionHandler: {(error) in
                    print("Remote Peer Local Description set " + error.debugDescription)
                })
                var remoteOfferParams: [String:String] = [:]
                remoteOfferParams["sdpOffer"] = sessionDescription!.sdp
                remoteOfferParams["sender"] = self.remoteParticipantId! + "_CAMERA"
                self.sendJson(method: "receiveVideoFrom", params: remoteOfferParams)
            })
            self.peersManager.remotePeer!.delegate = self.peersManager
        }
    }

    func saveAnswer(json: [String:Any]) {
        let sessionDescription = RTCSessionDescription(type: RTCSdpType.answer, sdp: json["sdpAnswer"] as! String)
        if localPeer == nil {
            self.localPeer = self.peersManager.localPeer
        }
        if (localPeer!.remoteDescription != nil) {
            participants[remoteParticipantId!]!.peerConnection!.setRemoteDescription(sessionDescription, completionHandler: {(error) in
                print("Remote Peer Remote Description set: " + error.debugDescription)
                if self.peersManager.remoteStreams.count >= self.participants.count {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Count: " + self.participants.count.description)
                        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
                            let renderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame:  self.views[self.participants.count-1].frame)

                            let videoTrack = self.peersManager.remoteStreams[self.participants.count-1].videoTracks[0]
                            videoTrack.add(renderer)
                            // Add the view and name to the first free space available
                            var index = 0
                            while (index < 2 && !(self.names[index].text?.isEmpty)!) {
                                index += 1
                            }
                            if index < 2 {
                                self.names[index].text = self.participants[self.remoteParticipantId!]?.participantName
                                self.names[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                                self.names[index].textColor = UIColor.white
                                self.embedView(renderer, into: self.views[index])
                                self.participants[self.remoteParticipantId!]?.index = index
                                self.views[index].bringSubview(toFront: self.names[index])
                            }
                        }else
                        {
                            #if arch(arm64)
                            let renderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame:  self.views[self.participants.count-1].frame)
                            #else
                            let renderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame:  self.views[self.participants.count-1].frame)
                            #endif

                            let videoTrack = self.peersManager.remoteStreams[self.participants.count-1].videoTracks[0]
                            videoTrack.add(renderer)
                            // Add the view and name to the first free space available
                            var index = 0
                            while (index < 2 && !(self.names[index].text?.isEmpty)!) {
                                index += 1
                            }
                            if index < 2 {
                                self.names[index].text = self.participants[self.remoteParticipantId!]?.participantName
                                self.names[index].backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                                self.names[index].textColor = UIColor.white
                                self.embedView(renderer, into: self.views[index])
                                self.participants[self.remoteParticipantId!]?.index = index
                                self.views[index].bringSubview(toFront: self.names[index])
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }
            })
        } else {
            localPeer!.setRemoteDescription(sessionDescription, completionHandler: {(error) in
                print("Local Peer Remote Description set: " + error.debugDescription)
            })
        }
    }

    func handleMethod(json: Dictionary<String,Any>) {
        if json[JSONConstants.Params] != nil {
            let method = json[JSONConstants.Method] as! String
            let params = json[JSONConstants.Params] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            switch method {
            case JSONConstants.IceCandidate:
                iceCandidateMethod(params: params)
            case JSONConstants.ParticipantJoined:
                participantJoinedMethod(params: params)

            case JSONConstants.ParticipantPublished:
                participantPublished(params: params)
            case JSONConstants.ParticipantLeft:
                participantLeft(params: params)
            default:
                print("Error handleMethod, " + "method '" + method + "' is not implemented")
            }
        }
    }
    func iceCandidateMethod(params: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        //        if (params["endpointName"] as? String == userId) {
        //            saveIceCandidate(json: params, endPointName: nil)
        //        } else {
        //            saveIceCandidate(json: params, endPointName: params["endpointName"] as? String)
        //        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if params["senderConnectionId"] != nil {
                self.key = "senderConnectionId"
            } else {
                self.key = "endpointName"
            }
            if (params[self.key ?? ""] as? String == self.userId) {
                self.saveIceCandidate(json: params, endPointName: params["endpointName"] as? String)
            } else {
                self.saveIceCandidate(json: params, endPointName: params[self.key ?? ""] as? String)
            }
        }
    }

//    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {
//        print("Received data: " + data.description)
//    }

    func participantJoinedMethod(params: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        let remoteParticipant = RemoteParticipant()
        remoteParticipant.id = params[JSONConstants.Id] as? String
        self.participants[params[JSONConstants.Id] as! String] = remoteParticipant
        let metadataString = params[JSONConstants.Metadata] as! String
        let data = metadataString.data(using: .utf8)!
        do {
            if let metadata = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String,Any>
            {
                remoteParticipant.participantName = metadata["clientData"] as? String
                self.peersManager.createRemotePeerConnection(remoteParticipant: remoteParticipant)

            } else {
                print("bad json")
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
        participantPublished(params: params)

    }

    func participantPublished(params: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        self.remoteParticipantId = params[JSONConstants.Id] as? String
        print("ID: " + remoteParticipantId!)
        let remoteParticipantPublished = participants[remoteParticipantId!]!
        let mandatoryConstraints = ["OfferToReceiveAudio": "true", "OfferToReceiveVideo": "true"]

        remoteParticipantPublished.peerConnection!.offer(for: RTCMediaConstraints.init(mandatoryConstraints: mandatoryConstraints, optionalConstraints: nil), completionHandler: { (sessionDescription, error) in
            remoteParticipantPublished.peerConnection!.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription!, completionHandler: {(error) in
                print("Remote Peer Local Description set")
            })
            var remoteOfferParams:  [String: String] = [:]
            remoteOfferParams["sdpOffer"] = sessionDescription!.description
            remoteOfferParams["sender"] = remoteParticipantPublished.id! + "_webcam"
            self.sendJson(method: "receiveVideoFrom", params: remoteOfferParams)
        })
        self.peersManager.remotePeer!.delegate = self.peersManager
    }

    func participantLeft(params: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        print("participants", participants)
        print("params", params)
        let participantId = params["connectionId"] as! String
        participants[participantId]!.peerConnection!.close()

        if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 {
            let renderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame:  self.views[0].frame)
            //REMOVE VIEW
            if(self.peersManager.remoteStreams.count > 0){

            let videoTrack = self.peersManager.remoteStreams[0].videoTracks[0]
            videoTrack.remove(renderer)
            if let index = self.participants.keys.index(of: participantId) {
                let i = participants.distance(from: participants.startIndex, to: index)
                self.views[i].willRemoveSubview(renderer)
                self.names[i].text = ""
                self.names[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
            }
            participants.removeValue(forKey: participantId)
        }else
        {
            #if arch(arm64)
            let renderer = RTCMTLVideoView(frame:  self.views[0].frame)
            #else
            let renderer = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame:  self.views[self.participants.count-1].frame)
            #endif
            //REMOVE VIEW

            if(self.peersManager.remoteStreams.count > 0){
                let videoTrack = self.peersManager.remoteStreams[0].videoTracks[0]
                videoTrack.remove(renderer)
                if let index = self.participants.keys.index(of: participantId) {
                    let i = participants.distance(from: participants.startIndex, to: index)
                    self.views[i].willRemoveSubview(renderer)
                    self.names[i].text = ""
                    self.names[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                }
                participants.removeValue(forKey: participantId)
            }

        }

    }

    func saveIceCandidate(json: Dictionary<String, Any>, endPointName: String?) {
        let iceCandidate = RTCIceCandidate(sdp: json["candidate"] as! String, sdpMLineIndex: json["sdpMLineIndex"] as! Int32, sdpMid: json["sdpMid"] as? String)
        if (endPointName == nil || participants[endPointName!] == nil) {
            self.localPeer = self.peersManager.localPeer
            self.localPeer!.add(iceCandidate)
        } else {
            participants[endPointName!]!.peerConnection!.add(iceCandidate)
        }
    }

    func sendJson(method: String, params: [String: String]) {
        let json: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        json.setValue(method, forKey: JSONConstants.Method)
        json.setValue(id, forKey: JSONConstants.Id)
        id += 1
        json.setValue(params, forKey: JSONConstants.Params)
        json.setValue(JSON_RPCVERSION, forKey: JSONConstants.JsonRPC)
        let jsonData: NSData
        do {
            jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions()) as NSData
            let jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
            print("Sending = \(jsonString)")
            socket.write(string: jsonString)
        } catch _ {
            print ("JSON Failure")
        }
    }

    func addIceCandidate(iceCandidateParams: [String: String]) {
        iceCandidatesParams!.append(iceCandidateParams)
    }

    func embedView(_ view: UIView, into containerView: UIView) {
        containerView.addSubview(view)
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.8)


        view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Any One who has used this code, needed help here. **I have Participant ID what is the way to get Audio Video streams, Do I need to make some connection(Peer connection)? or I will get these streams in the socket connection response only.**

Comment: Did you got any help , i am facing same issue , i tried to implement OpenVidu in native App but there is lots of issue , could you help me.

Comment: Not yet, Checkout this https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-tutorials/issues/105#event-3369853840

Comment: That issue is closed, it means still we are not able to use ios version

Comment: unfortunately Yes, let see if any person post answer here.